# Can't get data when passing two parameters on SQLite in React Native

Tags: sqlite, react-native, select, expo

I tried to pass two parametes like below for select query but I am no getting the data

```
db.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM data WHERE (month = ? AND items_id = ?);', ["Sep 2018",68], (_, { rows }) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
  });
});
```

**OutPut :**

```
{"_array":[],"length":0}
```

But is passed the value in query I got the out put like below

```
db.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM data WHERE (month = "Sep 2018" AND items_id = 68);', [], (_, { rows }) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
  });
});
```

**Output :**

```
{"_array":[{"item_id":"68","item_name":"Apple","month":"Sep 2018"}],"length":1}
```

**Note :**

I am using Expo Sqlite ("expo": "^27.0.1",)

```
import Expo, { SQLite } from 'expo';
const db = SQLite.openDatabase('itemsDb.db');
```

Kindly help to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Try to use sqlBatch instead of executeSql. I am using react-native-sqlite-storage without Expo and both works well.

Comment: @trubi plz explain in detail or provide reference

Answer (score 0):

It may have the same bug as in `react-native-sqlite-storage`:

The parameters are converted from numbers into strings making the query expression to fail, as the `items_id` column contain integers

One solution is to cast the value back to integer in the SQL command:

```sql
SELECT * FROM data WHERE (month = ? AND items_id = cast(? as integer))
```

The original bug is reported [here](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/issues/410#issuecomment-592672490)